# How to use if else conditions to create a new column and replace words with "Open Cases" and "Closed Cases" in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am learning to use python for data science and I have a dataset "Comcast complaints" in which there is a column called "Status" which contains the following strings.

[image]

How can I use if else condition to categorize strings of **"Open" & "Pending" as "Open Cases"**, **"Closed" & "Solved" as "Closed Cases"**

```
comcast_df['Status_New'] = comcast_df["Open Cases" if Status=="Open" or Status=="Pending" else "Closed Cases" for Status in comcast_df["Status"]]
```

I attempted the above line but it is going nowhere. I would appreciate any help in figuring out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you test `d = {"Open":"Open Cases", "Pending" :"Open Cases", "Closed" :"Closed Cases", "Solved":"Closed Cases"}` and then `comcast_df['Status_New'] = comcast_df["Status"].map(d)`

Comment: solution in dupe is general, here is possible use `map`, I guess better solution here